# HTML/CSS header is collapsing on the right when browser is in half screen

Tags: html, css

I've been learning HTML/CSS for about two weeks.

I've been making dummy websites just for practice and I've been struggling lately with a header problem. I will post code/pictures to help be as specific as I can.

I'm attempting to head a header on my web page with a solid background color going across the top, then a logo(title) on the left hand side of the header and a nav/search bar on the right hand side all within a container of 1020px.

Everything seems to look fine full screen but when I make my browser half width it seems to make my nav/search bar go off the screen on the right hand side and when I scroll over the header background color is missing.

I'm unsure why it's doing this so if someone has a fix could you explain to my not only why it's doing this but how/why I need to do what I need to do to fix it. Thank you so much!

My HTML file

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Dummy Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylez.css">
    </head>

    <body>


        <header>

            <div class="container">
                <div id="logo">
                    <h1>Another Dummy Site</h1>
                    <em>Just another dummy web page</em>
                </div>

                <div id="nav">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

                    <form>
                        <input type="search" placeholder="search 4 somethin">
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </header>

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
margin: 9;
padding: 9;
}
body {
font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
width: 109%;
background: #ccc;
}

header{
background: #fc9;
}

.container{
width: 1020px;
margin: 9 auto;
}

#logo{
float: left;
}

#nav{
float: right;
}
.clearfix::after{
content:"";
clear: both;
display: table;
}
```

Here is a pic of the site in full screen
[image]

Here is a pic of it in the browser half screen - notice the scroll bar and cut off on the right.
[image]

Here is a pic of when I scroll to the right
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't post pictures of code (post the code itself) and make a [mcve] - focus being on minimal. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.container {
   max-width:1020px;
   width:100%;
   margin:0 auto;
 }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smorris1900/oa68w2qb/)